# Why am I getting the error 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' when importing this .sql file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, import, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE `produtos` ( 
        `sku` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_store` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_attribute_set` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_category` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_product_websites` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `price` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `small_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `special_price` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `min_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `use_config_min_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `is_qty_decimal` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `backorders` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `use_config_backorders` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `min_sale_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `use_config_min_sale_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `max_sale_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `use_config_max_sale_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `is_in_stock` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `notify_stock_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `use_config_notify_stock_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `manage_stock` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `use_config_manage_stock` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `use_config_qty_increments` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `qty_increments` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `use_config_enable_qty_increments` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `enable_qty_increments` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_links_related_sku` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_links_related_position` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_links_crosssell_sku` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_links_crosssell_position` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_links_upsell_sku` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_links_upsell_position` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_associated_sku` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_associated_default_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_associated_position` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_tier_price_website` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_tier_price_customer_group` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_tier_price_qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
        `_tier_price_price` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES   
('RBA01,,Default,simple,Resinas,base,\"Resina: Acrílica Base Água [01 Kg]\",18.9000,/r/e/resina_base_agua_thumb.png,14.9000,0.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,0,,1,0,1,1,0.0000,1,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,'),
```

Comment: Because you're inserting a single string.  You need something more like `'RBA01',NULL,'Default', 'simple'`, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values in the INSERT are inside '' and are a single string for that command.

To elaborate: the error

```
Column count doesn't match value count
```

means that a INSERT command don't have the same number of values and columns. In you example, the insert command is with the default value for columns as you didn't inform any, so it will try to insert data in all columns, but as you value are inside ' ', it's treated as a single string.

Comment: I edited my answer with more info, as @Dems commented in your question you should separate your values at the INSERT command in multiply strings.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I'm trying to fix my query...
It's ok if I use `('\"Something here\"')` as a VALUE?
And instead of  `(',,,,Resinas/Tudo Na Categoria Atual,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'), ` I should do `('NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Resinas/Tudo Na Categoria Atual,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'), `?

Comment: Yes, for each column you should inform a value, separated by commas. Your example will only work if the columns are able to hold NULL values.

Comment: Try doing this in the INSERT:  INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES   
('RBA01','','Default','simple','Resinas','base,'Resina: Acrílica Base Água [01 Kg]', (...)